# How to empty the trash? (permanently delete)

Tags: 4.7, delete

I know you can permanently delete a deleted contact from the contact's screen, but **how can you en-masse delete all the deleted contacts** or "Empty Trash"?

Ideally delete all things trashed over 30 days ago would be fab.

It's especially needed for my client because [deleted contacts still show up in Constituent Summary and other reports](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20545)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Advanced Search, tick the box, 'search in trash'. hit 'enter/search' - that should give you all those in Trash (and ONLY those in Trash) and from Actions you can then choose 'permanently delete'

EDIT - can also be done via API Explorer: [Permanently delete more than 100k trashed records](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45452/permanently-delete-more-than-100k-trashed-records#45455)

Comment: Oh right, so Search In a Trash will *only* return contacts from trash, not all contacts *including* trash?

Comment: Correct, it only returns contacts in the trash.