# Permanently delete more than 100k trashed records

Tags: api, delete, clean

Is there a proper way to permanently delete more than 100k records already in trash ? For instance, Is there anyway to do this using the API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from the API4 explorer(CiviCRM >>> Support >> Developer >> API4 explorer).

[image]

Comment: Untick "useTrash" was the key. Thanks a lot!